Заголовок «Благодарности» в оглавлении книги
В книгах современных издательств часто можно встретить в оглавлении такой заголовок — Благодарности.
Действительно, слово "благодарность" имеет множественное число. Но автор выражает "благодарность", а не "благодарности", излагает "слова благодарности", а не "слова благодарностей".
Правильно ли писать в оглавлении заголовок "Благодарности"?

https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CuIBErsBCrgBChMKCWRpc2FtYm1vZBIGCgRtYWluChcKB2Rpc3Rtb2QSDAoKd2l0aF96ZXJvcxKHAQojCgNsZXgSHAoa0LHQu9Cw0LPQvtC00LDRgNC90L7RgdGC0YwKCgoEZm9ybRICCgAKFwoFZ3JhbW0SDgoMKG5vbSkgJiAocGwpCgkKA3NlbRICCgAKFQoHc2VtLW1vZBIKCghzZW18c2VteAoMCgZzeW50YXgSAgoACgsKBWZsYWdzEgIKACobCggIBxAKGDIgChAFIABABWoEMC45NXgAoAEBMgIIAToBAQ==
